Is the below given linear transformation using transformation matrix correct?
If I assume that the 3 vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ forms basis {$e_1,e_2,e_3$} of a vector space and A = $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&1\\2&5&7\end{bmatrix}$ as transformation matrix, if T is the transformation can I write
$$\begin{bmatrix}T(e_1)&T(e_2)&T(e_3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&1\\2&5&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e_1&e_2&e_3\end{bmatrix}$$
as
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&1\\2&5&7\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&1&1\\2&5&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
so, $T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix},T(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\5\end{bmatrix},T(\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\7\end{bmatrix}$
I will be grateful if someone could verify what I have written above is correct or not!

Are you familiar with the change of basis matrix?

I am familiar with the concept
